# Audio playlist - List dissapearing while selecting

Tags: jquery

I'm stucked on this... I have a section with several playlists and a main player that has a playlist loaded by default. When I click on an item from a list, I have to replace the current playlist with the new I clicked. 
My problem is that when I click on a 'li' from a playlistI want lo load, the content is loaded to the main playlist, but it dissapears from the playlist I clicked. I'm getting sick of this!! Could you help me? Thanks!

```
<ul class="audiolist">
    <li class="playcon"data="media/x.wav" data-autor="x"></li>
    <li class="playcon"data="media/x2.wav" data-autor="x"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="audiolist" id="randplay">
    <li data="media/01.mp3" data-autor="x">Nombre</li>
    <li data="media/02.mp3" data-autor="x2">Nombre</li>
    <li data="media/03.mp3" data-autor="x">Nombre</li>
    <li data="media/04.mp3" data-autor="x4">Nombre</li>
</ul>

<audio id="pla" src="" controls="controls";></audio>

<script>
    $('.audiolist li').click(function () {
        var newlist = $(this).parent();
        $('#randplay').html(newlist);

        var audiof = ($(this).attr('data'));
        var audioautor = ($(this).attr('data-autor'));

        $('#pla').attr('src',audiof);
        $('#autorspot').html(audioautor);
        $('#pla').attr('autoplay','auto');

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show us the actual problem?

Comment: So basically you want to replace the content of `randplay` with `audiolist` ?

Comment: And BTW - you're replacing it with an empty `LI`s, are you sure it disappears? What do you see when you inspect the element?

Comment: @AlonEitan what do you mean he replaces it with empty `li`s?

Comment: `<li class="playcon"data="media/x.wav" data-autor="x"></li>` For example - nothing inside the `LI`

Comment: @AlonEitan he's saying that the main list gets populated..

Comment: Oh.. This list also has the `.audiolist` class - this is what I think is the problem

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I don't understand why it changes the list i'm clicking! https://jsfiddle.net/nL6ks3o0/ I mean, I want to change just the #randplay

Answer (score 1):

I found it out! I was missing a .html() next to .parent(). Without it, it grabbed the content in place of copying it. Thanks to you all!

```
$('.audiolist li').click(function () {
var newlist = $(this).parent().html();
('#randplay').html(newlist);
```